# How do I configure an asa 5505 to limit users to only access only company resources and Skype?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, acl

I configured an asa 5505 to limit users to only access only company resources and skype. 
I got skype working but the company sites in the ACLs aren't accessible.

What am I doing wrong?

```
ASA Version 8.2(5)
!
firewall transparent
hostname ciscoasa
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/4
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/5
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/6
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/7
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no nameif
 no security-level
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
!
interface Vlan3
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
!
ftp mode passive
object-group network LIMITED_USERS
 network-object 192.168.108.64 255.255.255.192
object-group network ESSENTIALS
 network-object 196.33.158.28 255.255.255.255
 network-object 212.22.161.2 255.255.255.255
 network-object 196.30.251.214 255.255.255.255
 network-object 212.22.179.162 255.255.255.255
 network-object 41.78.37.84 255.255.255.255
 network-object 91.190.216.21 255.255.255.255
object-group service SKYPE
 service-object tcp-udp gt 1024
access-list LIMIT_TRAFFIC extended permit ip object-group LIMITED_USERS object-group ESSENTIALS
access-list LIMIT_TRAFFIC extended permit object-group SKYPE object-group LIMITED_USERS any
pager lines 24
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
ip address 192.168.108.6 255.255.255.0
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
access-group LIMIT_TRAFFIC in interface inside
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
aaa authentication http console LOCAL
http server enable
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
telnet 192.168.108.0 255.255.255.0 inside
telnet timeout 5
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
dhcpd option 3 ip 192.168.108.4
!
dhcpd address 192.168.108.65-192.168.108.96 inside
dhcpd enable inside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:ed62961c9bc8bc367be20c8c498bb290
: end
```

Output of `capture DENY type asp-drop all real-time trace`

```
 1: 00:58:52.033079 802.1Q vlan#2 P0 192.168.108.9.63084 > 239.255.255.250.3702:  udp 656
   2: 00:58:55.155570 802.1Q vlan#2 P0 fe80::49d5:e406:d284:1d36.546 > ff02::1:2.547:  udp 88 [hlim 1]
   3: 00:58:55.988291 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.63090 > 8.8.8.8.53:  udp 36
   4: 00:58:55.988397 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.63090 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 36
   5: 00:58:58.135643 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.51399 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 43 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by conf                      igured rule
   6: 00:58:59.134789 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.51399 > 8.8.8.8.53:  udp 43
   7: 00:59:00.035337 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.62398 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 36
   8: 00:59:00.134499 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.51399 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 43 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by conf                      igured rule
   9: 00:59:01.034406 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.62398 > 8.8.8.8.53:  udp 36 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by conf                      igured rule
  10: 00:59:02.034132 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.62398 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 36
  11: 00:59:02.134072 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.51399 > 8.8.8.8.53:  udp 43 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by conf                      igured rule
  12: 00:59:02.134163 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.51399 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 43 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by conf                      igured rule
  13: 00:59:03.117791 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.49972 > 79.119.88.88.1: S 3455399371:3455399371(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,                      wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK> Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
  14: 00:59:03.616728 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.49972 > 79.119.88.88.1: S 3455399371:3455399371(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,                      wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK>
  15: 00:59:04.033750 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.62398 > 8.8.8.8.53:  udp 36 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by conf                      igured rule
  16: 00:59:04.033857 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.62398 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 36 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by conf                      igured rule
  17: 00:59:04.116647 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.49972 > 79.119.88.88.1: S 3455399371:3455399371(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,                      nop,sackOK> Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
  18: 00:59:04.296585 802.1Q vlan#2 P0 fe80::9fd:d9c5:9aaf:6667.546 > ff02::1:2.547:  udp 82 [hlim 1]
  19: 00:59:06.134346 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.51399 > 8.8.8.8.53:  udp 43
  20: 00:59:06.134468 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.51399 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 43
  21: 00:59:08.033949 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.62398 > 8.8.8.8.53:  udp 36
  22: 00:59:08.034055 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.62398 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 36 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by conf
```

Comment: Have you got two classes of users?  Are there LIMITED_USERS defined by the ACL, and other users not in the LIMITED_USERS acl?  What source IP addresses cannot access your company resources?

Comment: There are two classes of users. The other class is not in this configuration is a group of SUPER_USERS that can access anything. That worked well but the LIMITED_USERS still could not access what I permited in the LIMIT_TRAFFIC ACL. The source ip addresses are in the range 192.168.108.65-192.168.108.96

Comment: Please run `capture DENY type asp-drop all real-time trace` while one of your LIMITED_USERS tries to access the company resources and add the output of that command to your question.  Also, after you finish with that command, you exit with `cntl-c` and need to remove the capture with `no capture DENY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in that capture...

1. DNS traffic is denied...

   `15: 00:59:04.033750 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.62398 > 8.8.8.8.53:  udp 36 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule`

   `16: 00:59:04.033857 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.62398 > 8.8.4.4.53:  udp 36 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule`
2. One of your clients is trying to go to 79.119.88.88.1, but it's denied...

   `17: 00:59:04.116647 802.1Q vlan#3 P0 192.168.108.65.49972 > 79.119.88.88.1: S 3455399371:3455399371(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK> Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule`

More than likely, your clients are using hostnames to go to some resource, and need to allow DNS traffic to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in `object-group network ESSENTIALS`.

In general, it's best just to make a rule that allows all DNS (i.e. destination udp/53), since DNS queries may recurse through other resolvers.

Comment: Thanks mate, really appreciate your help. Would upvote you but I don't have enough reputation (or badges) to do so.